# 2D Vector of Doubles sorting/editing issue

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix

I am working on a 2D vector of doubles matrix solver and my matrices keep turning out incorrectly.
The intended matrix output at "Level 3" is {(top, left to right)3,4 over (bottom, left to right)1,2} but my code keeps outputting {2,1 over 3,4}. I keep trying to invert the values but whenever I do so I keep getting an out of bounds exception.

```
 vector<double> gauss(mat B) {

 int n = B.A.size();

    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    // Search for maximum in this column
    double maxEl = abs(B.getSlot(i,i));
    int maxRow = i;
    for (int k=i+1; k<n; k++) {
        if (abs(B.getSlot(k,i)) > maxEl) {
            maxEl = abs(B.getSlot(k,i));
            maxRow = k;
        }
    }

    // Swap maximum row with current row
    for (int k=i; k<n+1;k++) {
        double tmp = B.getSlot(k,maxRow);
        B.editSlot(k,maxRow,B.getSlot(k,i));
        B.editSlot(k,i,tmp);
    }
 cout << "\n\nlevel 3: \n";
 B.display();

}
B.display();

// Solve equation Ax=b for an upper triangular matrix A
vector<double> x(n);

for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
    x[i] = B.getSlot(i,n)/B.getSlot(i,i);
    for (int k=i-1;k>=0; k--) {
        B.editSlot(k,n,B.getSlot(k,n)-B.getSlot(k,i)*x[i]);
    }
}
return x;
}


int main() {

int n = *Size of array is properly retrieved*

mat my_mat(n,n);

// Read input data
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        double myDub;
        inFile >> myDub;
        my_mat.editSlot(i,j,myDub);

    }
}

// Calculate solution
vector<double> x(n);
x = gauss(my_mat);
}
```

And my class code is as follows

```
class mat
{
public:

mat(int x,int y){
 int row = x;
  int col = y;
    n=row;

    A = vector<vector<double>>(row,vector<double>(row,0));


    for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<col; j++)
                {
                    cout<<setw(6)<<A[i][j];
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
        }

        void editSlot(int x, int y, double val){A[y][x] = val;}
        double getSlot(int x, int y){return A[y][x];}

     void display()
        {
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
                {
                    cout<<setw(6)<<A[j][i];
                }
                cout<<endl;
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }





 vector<vector<double>> A;

 private:
 int n;

 };
```

Comment: You should use `std::fabs()` instead of `abs()` for `double`s.

Comment: Thank you, @timrau. That doesn't solve my issue, but I implemented it none the less.

Comment: `for (int k=i; k<n+1;k++)` -- Anything that has `< n+1` as the loop terminator (and also `<=n`) is a sign that you may be going one over the boundaries of your vector.  Sprinkle `at()` calls instead of using `[ ]` to access the elements to see where the `std::out_of_range` exception is occurring.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie n+1 is fine if going horizontally on the matrix because there is a solution matrix on the far right.

Comment: @DaneHoward If everything worked in theory, there would be no bugs.  Your error, once you start using `at()` calls is exactly where I predicted.  When `k` is 2, you are out of bounds of your vector in the `getSlot` call, right where I pointed out the `< n + 1` suspect.  [See here, given the data you stated in the answer given by Pavel](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1188a50cfbdc015).  I will not post this as answer, since I do not know if you knew this was the problem and want to fix the code, or you didn't know where the problem was and  needed someone to point out where the problem is.

Comment: @DaneHoward Also note that the link shows how you should present a [mcve].  There are no calls to get input from a file, the headers are included, and the data that duplicates the issue is *hard-coded* into the program (no loops with `cin`, `scanf`, or whatever flavor input routine).  The program can literally be copied and pasted into another compiler's editor, the code will compile and run, *all without changing, adding, or removing any lines of code*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your input loop:

```
// Read input data
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        double myDub;
        inFile >> myDub;
        my_mat.editSlot(j, i, myDub);  // < - j, i swapped.
    }
}
```

Can you provide sample input that you use and what output you expect?

Comment: A sample input test would be 2 (rows and cols are equal) <new line> 1 2 <new line> 3 4 <new line> 10 <new line> 20. The expected output at Level 3 would be {(top row)3,4 (bottom row)1,2} but is currently {(tr)2,1 (br)4,3}

Comment: @DaneHoward Please hard-code this sample in the code you posted.  It is better to have the test data within the code than to have to fight through setting up data files or typing data from the keyboard each and every time.